# Spark scala - Nested StructType conversion to Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.6 in scala.

I created an index in ElasticSearch with an object. The object "params" was created as a Map[String, Map[String, String]]. Example:

```
val params : Map[String, Map[String, String]] = ("p1" -> ("p1_detail" -> "table1"), "p2" -> (("p2_detail" -> "table2"), ("p2_filter" -> "filter2")), "p3" -> ("p3_detail" -> "table3"))
```

That gives me records that look like the following:

```
{
        "_index": "x",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "_score": 1,
        "_timestamp": 1506537199650,
        "_source": {
           "a": "toto",
           "b": "tata",
           "c": "description",
           "params": {
              "p1": {
                 "p1_detail": "table1"
              },
              "p2": {
                 "p2_detail": "table2",
                 "p2_filter": "filter2"
              },
              "p3": {
                 "p3_detail": "table3"
              }
           }
        }
     },
```

Then I am trying to read the Elasticsearch index in order to update the values.

Spark reads the index with the following schema:

```
|-- a: string (nullable = true)
|-- b: string (nullable = true)
|-- c: string (nullable = true)
|-- params: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- p1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- p1_detail: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- p2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- p2_detail: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- p2_filter: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- p3: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- p3_detail: string (nullable = true)
```

My problem is that the object is read as a struct. In order to manage and easily update the fields I want to have a Map as I am not very familiar with StructType.

I tried to get the object in a UDF as a Map but I have the following error:

```
 User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(params)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires map<string,map<string,string>> type, however, 'params' is of struct<p1:struct<p1_detail:string>,p2:struct<p2_detail:string,p2_filter:string>,p3:struct<p3_detail:string>> type.;
```

UDF code snippet:

```
val getSubField : Map[String, Map[String, String]] => String = (params : Map[String, Map[String, String]]) => { val return_string = (params ("p1") getOrElse("p1_detail", null.asInstanceOf[String]) return_string }
```

My question: How can we convert this Struct to a Map? I already read saw the toMap method available in the documentation but can not find how to use it (not very familiar with implicit parameters) as I am a scala beginner.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you please add UDF code snippet?

Comment: The UDF is not going to help a lot as I am just trying to get a Map[String, Map[String, String]] where a Struct is expected.

Comment: `val getSubField : Map[String, Map[String, String]] => String = (params : Map[String, Map[String, String]])  => {
      
 val return_string = (params ("p1") getOrElse("p1_detail", null.asInstanceOf[String])
      
 return_string
}`

Comment: I can replace the "params" type with SructType but then I just don't know how to convert it to a Map.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to specify StructType object as param as they meant to represent collection schema, instead define type as Row. check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it as follows:

```
def convertRowToMap[T](row: Row): Map[String, T] = {
  row.schema.fieldNames
    .filter(field => !row.isNullAt(row.fieldIndex(field)))
    .map(field => field -> row.getAs[T](field))
    .toMap
}

/* udf that converts Row to Map */
val rowToMap: Row => Map[String, Map[String, String]] = (row: Row) => {
  val mapTemp = convertRowToMap[Row](row)
  
  val mapToReturn = mapTemp.map { case (k, v) => k -> convertRowToMap[String](v) }
  
  mapToReturn   
}
val udfrowToMap = udf(rowToMap)
```

Comment: thanks mate, your solution helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify type of param as StructType object, instead specify type as Row.

```
//Schema of parameter
def schema:StructType = (new StructType).add("p1", (new StructType).add("p1_detail", StringType))
      .add("p2", (new StructType).add("p2_detail", StringType).add("p2_filter",StringType))
      .add("p3", (new StructType).add("p3_detail", StringType))

 //Not allowed
 val extractVal: schema => collection.Map[Nothing, Nothing] = _.getMap(0)
```

**Solution:**

```
// UDF example to process struct column
val extractVal: (Row) => collection.Map[Nothing, Nothing] = _.getMap(0)

// You would implement something similar
   val getSubField : Map[String, Map[String, String]] => String =
  (params : Row) =>
  {
    val p1 = params.getAs[Row]("p1")
    .........
    return null;
  }
```

I hope this helps !