# Spark Dataframe(Scala) to concatenate arrays(as StructField) within StructType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**I have a dataframe with this schema**:

```
 root  
 |-- customer_id: string (nullable = true)  
 |-- service: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- cat1: array (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)  
 |    |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |    |-- match_id: string (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- cat2: array (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)  
 |    |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |    |-- match_id: string (nullable = true)
```

**actual data looks like this:**

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|customer_id|service                                                                        |  
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|CID1       |[[[cat1, service1], [cat1, service3]],]                                        |  
|CID2       |[[[cat1, service4],], [[cat2, service7], [cat2, service8], [cat2, service9]]]  |  
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**I hope transformed data can look like this:**

```
+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|customer_id|  cat |  service                                                                 |  
+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|CID1       | cat1 | [[cat1, service1], [cat1, service3]]                                     |  
|CID2       | cat1 | [[cat1, service4]]                                                       |
|CID2       | cat2 | [[cat2, service7], [cat2, service8], [cat2, service9]]                   |  
+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

or even better(but it'll be simple if I can do above form)

```
+-----------+------+-----------------------------------+  
|customer_id|  cat |  service                          |  
+-----------+------+-----------------------------------+  
|CID1       | cat1 | [service1, service3]              |  
|CID2       | cat1 | [service4]                        |
|CID2       | cat2 | [service7, service8, service9]]   |  
+-----------+------+-----------------------------------+
```

where service is a concatenation of original cat1 and cat2.

***And 1 thing to notice is there could be many fields under original service, meaning there could be cat1, cat2, cat3 ...***

I'm new to Scala as well as Spark, and have searched for a while, but haven't seen similar examples.

Comment: sorry I changed the question a bit, because I realized the actual form I wanted was incorrect. Since there wasn't a correct answer yet, so I guess it's fine.

Comment: To break up the `service` struct into its components, try `df.select("service.*")`.

Comment: @NickChammas no, df.select("service.*)) explode horizontally, what I need is explode vertically -- turn fields into rows instead of columns

Comment: I found this question is similar to mine, and I actually solved my problem using partially the solution there.

Comment: I found this question is similar to mine, and I actually solved my problem using partially the solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566374/spark-scala-nested-structtype-conversion-to-map. The steps are: 1. turn the structype to Map, then explode the Map column, then I got my result. I'll mark my question as duplicate

Comment: Sorry, careless reading on my part. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

you could explode your service column twice and collect list by grouping customer_id:

```
val explodedOnceDF = df.select(col("customer_id"),explode("service").as("service"))
val explodedTwiceDF = explodedOnceDF.select(col("customer_id"),explode("service").as("service"))
val requiredOutput = explodedTwiceDF.groupBy("customer_id").agg(collect_list("service").as("service")).select(col("customer_id"),col("service"))
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: mate, it doesn't work. Because "service" column is of struct type, you can only explode array or map types